# How to print database data into 4x4 format,just like we see on shopping websites?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am doing this program in php.

```
foreach ($rs_result as $value) {
echo $value['name']; 

for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<4;$j++)
    {
    echo $value['name'];
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

it is printing same data 4 times(5 times first loop) not different one.

Comment: unclear question

Comment: Count till 4, after that clear counter and count again.

Comment: @ShobiPP what is unclear?

Comment: @u_mulder let me try that.

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks,it is working but each columns are in different sizes,how can i solve it?

Comment: I don't see any columns here.

Comment: @u_mulder i meant each echo .

Comment: @u_mulder when i echo <form> inside that loop ,each of them appear below their previous one not in 4x4 format,why is that happening?

Comment: Please, ask a new question provide detailed data on what is wrong. I don't understand what for you use `form` and what is wrong with it.

Comment: @u_mulder just solved it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best thing to use here would be to [array chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) your product results and then loop through this result set. An example can be seen below.

```
$chunk = array_chunk($rs_result, 4);

//this will loop through each row
foreach($chunk as $row){

    //this will be used to get each item on row
    foreach ($row as $item){

    }
}
```

then simply style out how you want your results to be shown or which data from each result.

Comment: suggestion(in comment) from @u_mulder works but not in right format so let me check what is array_chunk & try your way.

Comment: there's plenty of ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: thanks for introducing Array_chunk to me,the code works fine...upvoted & ticked as an answer.

Comment: when i echo <form> inside that loop ,each of them appear below their previous one not in 4x4 format,why is that happening?

Comment: i am making product catalog from where i can add items into cart thats why i had to add form each time loop runs

Comment: you can enquire if you need further help using the email on my profile or you can ask a new question on the forum

Comment: sorry but what is unsing means?

Comment: using* if you want more help, contact me on my email address on my stack overflow profile